# Applying animation at the same time of fragment transition

Tags: java, android, transition, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have an activity with an appBarLayout & collapsingToolBar and a child fragment. The child fragment transitions to other fragments with a slide animation. I've created an animation xml for this slide transition which works fine. Each fragment shows a different title in the collapsingToolBar.

However, I need the title in the collapsingToolBar to transition along with the fragment when it is replaced. I tried to access the title from the collapsingToolBar so I could animate it, but I found out that the title is not a textView.

My next option was to animate the whole collapsingToolBar itself.

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slideLeft, R.anim.slideRight);
    transaction.replace(id, newFragment);
    transaction.commit();

    Animation rightToLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slideLeft);
    collapsingToolbar.startAnimation(rightToLeft);
```

However, the title seems to be animating in first slightly compared to the fragment. Is there a way I can get the title and fragment to transition in together at the same time? Thanks!